# Using tar to unpack file to directory while shell is somewhere else

Tags: bash, tar

I thought this would of been a simple question to answer, but everywhere I turn EVERYONE expects the tar to be in the same directory as the shell.

My file is located:

```
/tmp/my_file.tar.gz
```

I want to extract it to the following directory:

```
/opt/
```

My shell is currently located at:

```
~/
```

Answer (score 4):

1. GNU `tar`has a `-C` (or `--directory`) option that you can use. For example

   ```
   tar -C /opt -x -z -f /tmp/my_file.tar.gz
   ```

   or
2. You can use a simple subshell. For example

   ```
   (cd /opt; tar -xvzf /tmp/my_file.tar.gz)
   ```

   after this, your current directory is still `~/`, the `cd` only affects the subshell. This approach is useful for commands and utilities that lack a `-C` option or equivalent.

Note that you must make sure that the paths stored in the tar file are *relative paths* not *absolute paths*. This is determined by the command used to create the tar file. You can check this using `tar -tzf ...` and inspecting the first character of the paths (e.g. `/foo/...` is an absolute path, `foo/...` or `./foo/...` are relative). Be especially careful if running this as root. You'd be in a world of hurt if somewhere in a long list of relative paths there is a `/etc/passwd` or worse. But see [GNU tar -P option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/absolute.html) - this *may* not be an issue on your specific platform. I'd check carefully before proceeding.